# restart pulseaudio after pactl exit

Tags: pulseaudio

After running `pactl exit` I can't get it running again. Music is playing but it doesn't reach the speaker.

Is there a way to start it up again, or is rebooting the only option?

Comment: Hi WuerfelDev, welcome to the unix & linux stack exchange. By the sounds of your question, @Ipor Sircer's answer below should do the trick for you. However for future reference, it's a good idea to be as thourough as possible with your question to ensure the community understands exactly what you're asking. useful info would be what you've tried to do to fix it so far, and any errors you encounter along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply start `pulseaudio` again.
Type `pulseaudio` then press enter.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the solution for me, but I found the root of my problem: The sink was in suspended state. I wasn't able to change anything about it, only restart helped :(